# Clickhouse: runningAccumulate() does not work as I expect

Tags: clickhouse

Say, we have a table `testint`.

```sql
        SELECT *
    FROM testint
    
    ┌─f1─┬─f2─┐
    │  2 │  3 │
    │  2 │  3 │
    │  4 │  5 │
    │  4 │  5 │
    │  6 │  7 │
    │  6 │  7 │
    └────┴────┘
```

We try to query `runningAccumulate()` with `sumState()`.

```sql
    SELECT runningAccumulate(col)
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT sumState(f1) AS col
        FROM testint
        GROUP BY f1
    )
    
    ┌─runningAccumulate(col)─┐
    │                      8 │
    │                     12 │
    │                     24 │
    └────────────────────────┘
```

Why is the first row in the response `8`, and not `4`? If we are grouping by f1, the first row seems to be `4` (we do sum the first `2` and the second `2` in the column `f1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accumulate-functions the order of elements is important, so just add *ORDER BY* to fix it:

```sql
SELECT runningAccumulate(col)
FROM 
(
    SELECT sumState(f1) AS col
    FROM testint
    GROUP BY f1
    ORDER BY f1 ASC /* <-- */
)
```

You got the result *[8, 12, 24]* for input data *[8, 4, 12]* when should be used the ordered input - *[4, 8, 12]*.